# Derivation of the Macdonald operator $D_{n}(X;q,t)$

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

Since I first encountered Equation (3.2) on p.315 of Macdonald's *Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials*, I have wanted to know where it comes from. So how does one derive the operator

\begin{equation}
D_{n}(X;q,t) = a_{\delta}(x)^{-1}\sum_{w \in S_{n}} \varepsilon(w)x^{w\delta}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+Xt^{(w\delta)_{i}}T_{q,x_{i}})
\end{equation}

in the first place?

Comment: It is a very long story. But perhaps you can clarify: do you mean, why did Macdonald think of that particular operator, or what is the best way to motivate it today, with the benefit of hindsight?

Comment: I was definitely wondering how did Macdonald think of that particular operator. Although, I would most definitely be interested in motivation with the benefit of hindsight. If the story is indeed very long, could you perhaps point me in the right direction?